How do I split the bibliography in two parts?
I want to split Bibliography into two sections, Works Cited, and References, in MLA convention. (Bibliography in MLA is non numbered and alphabetical)

Please add a short, but compilable test file which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a document environment.

\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage [utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage[style=mla]{biblatex}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\theendnotes
\printbibliography (Generates what I cite. I want to generate everything from my Mendeley library, in a separate "References" section in Bibliograpy)


Please edit your question and test if the code actually compiles.
